# What can I add to this parsing code to notify the user if there's an issue?

Tags: python, parsing, notifications

So I have this script that reads an inventory log and it needs to notify the user if the parsed string is not the string that is desired. For example if it reads on the Memory bracket reads 80877 MB it should read 81877 MB and user should be notified with a message saying "Error in memory should be 81877 MB where it reads 80877 MB" and so on and so forth. Any ideas?

>

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/build/sars")


def rescanips():


     data = {}

fileIN = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

line = fileIN.readline()

for line in file_obj:
    if ':' in line:
         pos = line.index(':')
         data[line[:pos].strip()] = line[pos + 1:].strip()

for key in data: print key, ':', data[x]

f.close()
```

Inventory Log

Processor               : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 v2 @ 2.20GHz (24 cores/threads)

Memory                  : 81877MB

Controller Slot         : 0

BIOS                    : 3.0a 11/12/2013 3.1

IPMI FW rev             : 2.20

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the log file you're reading in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that `key` would be `Memory` and `data[x]` would be `81877MB`. If you know the exact value you should be seeing, you can just do this:

```
if key == "Memory":
  if data[x] != "81877MB":
    sys.stderr.write("Error in memory: should be 81877MB where it reads " + data[x] + "\n")
```

If you have a more general, non-exact expectation of what value you need, you need to use regular expressions, probably.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Let me know if I'm missing something here, but it seems pretty straightforward.